# Is /dev/zero Unsafe to Use on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, dd, windows-10-desktop

So I ran the following command in Cygwin: `dd if=/dev/zero of=E:`

Now my C: drive lost all its free space. Upon unpluggin my E: drive from its USB port, the PC automatically shuts down. Is /dev/zero being created within the C: drive, and if so does that make it potentially unsafe to use with Cygwin?

Comment: You probably created a file named `E:` -- but this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing directly to disks is really **DANGEROUS** on any system

On cygwin the disks as physical entities are not the windows letter `E:` or the logical `/cygdrive/e` entities

If you want to completely overwrite the physical structure

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXX
```

Pay **REALLY** attention to your final destination, or you will
**BLOW** your system.

/dev/sda     full first disk
/dev/sda1    first disk, first partition
/dev/sdb     full second disk
/dev/sdb1    second disk, first partition
and so on...